# Angular JS routing not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs

While i am trying to click on **show** its not showing any thing, i have wasted lot of time on this, but no luck can some one help.

Files....

1. app.js
2. controller.js
3. index.html
4. show.html

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app='Java4sApp'>
<head>
    <title>Angular Js Tutorials _ Java4s</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<div ng-controller='Java4sController'>



            Settings :
            <a href="#add">Add Details</a> | <a href="#show">Show Details</a> 

            <div ng-view></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**show.html**

```
<html ng-app='Java4sApp'>
<head>
    <title>Angular Js Tutorials _ Java4s</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller='Java4sController'>


            <input type="text" ng-model="myModel" />

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat='person in people | filter:myModel'>{{person.name}}</li>
            </ul>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**controller.js**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
      when('/add', {
        controller: 'Java4sController',
        templateUrl: '/add.html'
    }).
      when('/show', {
        controller: 'Java4sController',
        templateUrl: '/show.html'
    }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/index.html'
      });
}]);

app.controller("Java4sController",function($scope){

        $scope.people = [
            {name: 'Siva', city: 'Cary'},
            {name: 'Teja', city: 'Raleigh'},
            {name: 'Reddy', city: 'Durham'},
            {name: 'Venky', city: 'Denver'},
            {name: 'Arun', city: 'Texas'}
    ];

});
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("Java4sApp",[]);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any error in your console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to inject the 'ngRoute' dependency when you are creating your module.

```
var app= angular.module('Java4sApp', [
  'ngRoute'
]);
```

Also make sure you obtain Angular routing js and add a reference to it, in your index.html

```
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
```

A good example can be found [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

Please let me know if this doesn't fix your problem

**UPDATE**

This is a simple **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl%3awUhAGG)** that shows AngularJS Routing

Comment: Hi Thara, added, but no luck, if possible can you connect my system.

Comment: In some examples, they did not added ngRoute, its bit confusing me Thara.

Comment: I see quite a few problems in your code. 
1. I cannot see you have used ngView
2. You are attempting to share multiple controllers (which is bad)
Let me put up a plunker n see

Comment: Okay, this seems to be a good pluker for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/wUhAGG?p=preview . Hope this helps :).

Comment: How did you go with fixing your problem. If you found my answer is correct and helpful could please mark this as the answer as explained here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Sure thara,  http://plnkr.co/edit/wUhAGG?p=preview helped me...!
Thanks for your time, god bless you.

Comment: Thara, one final doubt, in http://plnkr.co/edit/wUhAGG?p=preview you are included the .js libraries before closing the body tag, why ? generally we used to define in the header right ? what is the difference.

Comment: You can add js either in header or any part of the body. For performance, it's best to add these js at the bottom of the JS. This is well explained here - http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html (check the 'Put Scripts at the Bottom' topic). Happy coding. Ask me if you need to clear any other doubts (By the Plunker is not something I did ;))

Comment: In case the _nav.html is a form with some input controls and I want to post the data to the server. How do I do that? How do I add the controller?